# Ruby on Rails No route matches [GET] "/manager/html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see this error many times in my Ruby on Rails log file. I don´t know where does it come from?

```
F, [2015-07-13T13:03:00.178740 #22638] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/manager/html"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:490:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:361:in `process_client'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:96:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:96:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: in production or in development mode? on the local system or on a production system? somebody/something calls manager/html on production system it could be an bot which is looking for something like phpmyadmin e.g.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of this error message in production server, hopefully someone comes out with a solution other than [this one](http://rubyjunky.com/cleaning-up-rails-4-production-logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

> These errors represent lame attempts by hackers to exploit various
>   known vulnerabilities in other applications.

[See more details about it here.](http://rubyjunky.com/cleaning-up-rails-4-production-logging.html)